# If $\mathcal{C}$ is the category with one object, then a natural transformation from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{D}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm not sure what suffices as a proof of the above statement. We know that a functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ is equivalent to a choice of an object in $\mathcal{D}$, so this statement seems to follow from the commutativity condition on the natural transformation. In particular, there is only one morphism in $\mathcal{C}$, namely, the identity. Then, given two functors $F, G$, the morphism in $\mathcal{D}$ is essentially between $F(id)$ and $G(id)$ (although I'm not actually sure what these look like).

Can you help me expand on these ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to every natural transformation a morphism $\phi$ corresponds. But if ${\rm Hom}(c,c)\ne \{id\}$ then not every morphis is suitable, only "intertwining" one, i.e. such that $\phi F(f)=G(f)\phi$ for $f\in{\rm Hom}(c,c)$.

Comment: So how would you prove the above statement?

Comment: It needs no proof, it is a definition of a  natural transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Let us exploit the definition of natural transformation.

**In general.** 
Let $F,G:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ be two functors between *any* categories. A natural transformation $\eta:F\rightarrow G$ assigns to every object $C\in\textrm{Ob}\,\mathcal C$ an arrow $\eta_C:FC\to GC$ in $\mathcal D$ such that for every arrow $f:C\to C'$ in $\mathcal C$ there is a commutative diagram in $\mathcal D$ (assume $F,G$ covariant):

[image]

**In our case.**
Let $C$ be the unique object in $\mathcal C$. Let us assume the unique arrow in $\mathcal C$ is $f=1_C$. Let us look at what becomes the above diagram:
a natural transformation $\eta:F\Rightarrow G$ is an arrow $\eta_C:FC\to GC$ plus the condition $G(1_C)\circ \eta_C=\eta_C\circ F(1_C)$. But $F(1_C)=1_{FC}$ and $G(1_C)=1_{GC}$ so the condition "the square is commutative" is vacuous.

We are left with the arrow $\eta_C$.

Comment: Ah, this makes it much more clear in my mind. Thank you!